# Laravel 5 Elixir css/js not coming into public/ directory after running 'gulp' in CLI

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I read the documentation available for Laravel 5's new Elixir.

I have written this code and run gulp multiple times, however, the compiled/minified css and js are not coming in:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix
    .styles([
        "resources/assets/components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
    ])
    .scripts([
        "resources/assets/components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
    ])
    .version('css/app.css');
});
```

I've run `npm install` and `gulp` in the CLI and I get this output (which seems normal):

```
[05:15:58] Starting 'default'...
[05:15:58] Starting 'styles'...
[05:16:00] Finished 'default' after 1.32 s
[05:16:00] Finished 'styles' after 1.32 s
[05:16:00] Starting 'scripts'...
[05:16:00] Finished 'scripts' after 456 ms
[05:16:00] Starting 'version'...
[05:16:00] Finished 'version' after 2.6 ms
vagrant@homestead:~/Code/fixer$
```

What's the problem here?  I also watched the Laracast and it seems I'm doing everything properly.

It's difficult to find a good answer given this is new.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Elixir will assume that the stylesheets and scripts that you're concatenating are located in the public/ directory. To override that, set the base directory.

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix
        .styles([
            "components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
        ], "resources/assets")
        .scripts([
            "components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
        ], "resources/assets")
        .version('css/app.css');
});
```

(But also remember that you're trying to concatenate one file in each of those blocks... Maybe that was just for your code snippet.)

Comment: The legend himself solves my problem.  Thanks. (yes it was just an example).  It should still work even if there's only one file, right?

Comment: Yes. I just tried out my code example with Elixir, and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Check your `package.json` file - I've been trying to fix this issue for myself this morning, and it turns out that Elixir is a little buggy at the moment.

I'd been trying to run multiple `.scripts()` functions (one for head scripts, one for foot scripts) which didn't work until I found [this post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-elixir-multiple-sets-of-scripts) which said to update to version 0.4.x of Elixir. I did that, and suddenly the scripts seemed to be compiling.

Then they stopped appearing in `/public/js` for no reason that I could find, and downgrading back to 0.3.* has made them come back.

My `package.json` looks like this right now:

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "^3.8.9",
        "laravel-elixir": "^0.3.*"
    }
}
```

Comment: Changed `package.json` and ran `npm update`, then ran `gulp`.  Still not there.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
Just started to debug this and so far I can tell that problem is caused by the fact that there is incorrect src variable passed to gulp-less from elixir:

```
[ 'undefined/resources/assets/less/site.less' ]
```

As you can see, it is prefixed by "undefined".

If one would pass correct path string into the function (in GulpCssCompiler), then it works fine.

```
return gulp.src('resources/assets/less/site.less')
            .pipe(plugins[options.pluginName](options.pluginOptions))
```

I will look into this some more.

EDIT:
There seems to be an error in 'GulpCssCompiler.js' file.
Short fix:
Replace on line 11:

```
    options.src, options.assetsDir, options.search
```

with:

```
    options.src, config.assetsDir, options.search
```

and use 'less/file.less' in gulpfile (this presumes that resources/assets is the assetsdir)

Comment: my pull request was just merged into elixir package, so in theory you can do an update and it should work. https://github.com/laravel/elixir/pull/16 Remember to use 'less/filename.less' in gulpfile, if it does not work out of the box.

Comment: Slight misread from my side. But as you can see, the issue is/was in the proper assetdir.