# Laravel Elixir: Gulp won't compile Bootstrap Sass files

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

So I started with Laravel 5, Elixir and Bower and followed the guide published on [laravel-news](https://laravel-news.com/2014/10/setting-laravel-elixr-bootstrap/).

I managed to compile all scripts but Gulp won't compile the Bootstrap Sass files even if it says `Finished 'sass' after 228 ms`.
This is what I have in my gulpfile atm:

```
var paths = {
    'bootstrap': './vendor/bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/'
}

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass("style.scss", 'public/css/', {includePaths: [paths.bootstrap + 'stylesheets/']})
});
```

But when I run gulp there is no `css`
 directory with the css file in it.
What could the problem be? I really don't know what's the problem.

I'm running on Mac OSX (10.10), MAMP and updated all apps, dependencies etc.
As stated in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500755/laravel-5-elixir-css-js-not-coming-into-public-directory-after-running-gulp-i/26528211#26528211) I checked if Elixir is the latest version and it is (`*` and no specific version).

Is there a way to debug Elixir? I have not found anything about this.

---

**Solution posted in [this answer](/questions/28331203/laravel-elixir-gulp-wont-compile-bootstrap-sass-files/31720836#31720836)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**
It wasn't the wrong path but more that I misunderstood the documentation of the function. The `includePaths:` does not tell Sass to include them into the CSS file. It tells Sass where to look for files that were imported with `@import`.

*gulpfile.js*

```
var bower_path = "./vendor/bower_components";
var paths = {
  'jquery'     : bower_path + "/jquery/dist",
  'bootstrap'  : bower_path + "/bootstrap-sass-official/assets",
  'fontawesome': bower_path + "/fontawesome"
};

mix.sass("app.scss", "public/assets/css", {
  includePaths: [
    paths.bootstrap + '/stylesheets',
    paths.fontawesome + '/scss'
  ]
});
```

*resources/assets/sass/app.scss*

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome";
```

With this code I was able to compile a CSS file.

The complete code can be found at the [InvoicePlane repo at Github](https://github.com/InvoicePlane/InvoicePlane-V2/commit/1aebc9e8ce16f7072720667881d5186c8d3a0667).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your path.

According to the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/elixir), your scss file is assumed to be in `resources/assets/sass`. Elixir's default config path for bower is `vendor/bower_components`, which is what you seem to be trying to point to as well. If you need to change it, just create an `elixir.json` file in the root of the project with a new bower path.

```
{
  bowerDir: 'your/new/path'
}
```

Bootstrap's scss is already included in Elixir's `ingredients/sass.js`.

```
includePaths: [elixir.config.bowerDir + "/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets"]
```

Also, you're including the default css output path in your `sass()` argument. So if your custom scss file is `resources/assets/scss/style.scss` and `vendor/bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets` is a valid path you should just need

```
elixir(function(mix) {
  mix.sass("style.scss");
});
```

and it will compile your scss into `public/css`. In my experience, my bower installs have gone into `/bower_components`. I think the beta release of Laravel that that tutorials was based off of included a `.bowerrc` file, which tells bower to install libraries in the `vendor` directory. In a stable install, I don't have the `.bowerrc` file. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is using this line to compile sass or less files sitting in your vendor folder:

```
mix.less("../../../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less");
```

Note: I used "composer require twbs/boostrap" to get the complete package. No bower needed.

Edit:

I output the compiled css file to the resource folder to combine it with other css files:

```
mix.less("../../../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less", 'resources/css');


mix.styles([
    "bootstrap.css"
], 'public/css/app.css');
```